# Is there a difference between normal forces and centripetal forces?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, centripetal-force

Is there a difference between [normal forces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_force) and [centripetal forces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force)? Or they just mean the same thing? My textbook talks about centripetal forces, but not about normal ones.

Comment: What about e.g. the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_force) doesn't satisfy you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal forces, as the name implies, are those forces that are normal to a surface. Most often, these are also reaction forces imposed by the surface in response to some externally allied force.

Centripetal forces are those that produce circular motion. They are the forces that point to the center of revolution. Centripetal force can be caused by a normal force, but it can also be caused by other forces. Earth orbits the Sun with the force of gravity acting as the centripetal force keeping the motion relatively circular.

Furthermore, not all normal forces are centripetal forces. The normal force on you that keeps you from accelerating through the ground does not produce any circular motion. It is a normal force, but not centripetal.